# Android - going back to previous app gives strange message

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, back-button

I am using this code to go back to the previous activity in Android:

```
@ReactMethod
  public void  goBack()
  {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    MainApplication.getContext().startActivity(startMain);
  }
```

The problem is when I open a link (deep link) from Gmail for example, my app opens on top of the Gmail app and when I'm pressing the back button it shows me the following message:
[image]

What I want is to go back to the previous app or to the Home screen without finishing or killing my app.

I want it to be as if I pressed the multi-apps button and chosen the previous app without closing my app. When I'm using the back button as it is it finishes my app.
I tried playing with the flags but without success.

There is a Cordova solution for this : https://github.com/mohamed-salah/phonegap-backbutton-plugin/blob/master/src/android/BackbuttonPlugin.java. Mine is a React Native project.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I used a different code:

```
@ReactMethod
  public void  goBack()
  {
    MainApplication.getCurrentActivity().moveTaskToBack (true);

  }
```

In MainApplication.java:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication 
{


    private static Activity currentActivity;

    @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Used for BackButton Module
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
          @Override
          public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              MainApplication.currentActivity = activity;
          }

          @Override
          public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
              MainApplication.currentActivity = activity;
          }

          @Override
          public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
              MainApplication.currentActivity = activity;
          }

          @Override
          public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
              MainApplication.currentActivity = null;
          }

          @Override
          public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
              // don't clear current activity because activity may get stopped after
              // the new activity is resumed
          }

          @Override
          public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
              // don't clear current activity because activity may get destroyed after
              // the new activity is resumed
          }
      });
      }
      public static Activity getCurrentActivity()
      {
          return currentActivity;
      }
}
```